# ffmpeg, /dev/video0, -f decklink

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to capture video from a PCI card, the Blackmagic DeckLink Mini Recorder, via ffmpeg, on a headless host running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, hopefully with a command like

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -i /dev/video0 ...
```

How can I make that work?  I have two obstacles.

### No /dev/video0

`ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 ...` fails: `/dev/video0: No such device or address`.
`v4l2-ctl --list-devices` fails with the same error message.

I built /dev/video0, and it looks okay:

```
mknod /dev/video0 c 81 0
chown root.video /dev/video0
chmod g+rw /dev/video0
```

To compare this file with a working one, I ran `strace cat /dev/video0` on this host, and on another host (Ubuntu 14) with a working /dev/video0.  The outputs began to differ here (good, then bad):

```
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/dev/video0", O_RDONLY)           = 3  
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(81, 0), ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
----

fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/video0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
```

So /dev/video0 is broken at a level lower than ffmpeg or v4l2 or even cat.

On Ubuntu 14, `man 8 MAKEDEV` suggests that the error message means that "the kernel does not have the driver configured or loaded."

This Ubuntu 18 host lacks that manpage, but it does have a few `/snap/core/*/sbin/MAKEDEV`, all the same, so I tried

```
/snap/core/6350/sbin/MAKEDEV -n -v video
```

It would have created over a hundred devices videoXX, radioXX, vtxXX, vbiXX.  Those devices didn't exist yet, so it seemed harmless to try it.

```
rm /dev/video0; /snap/core/6350/sbin/MAKEDEV video
```

That rebuilt /dev/video0, but "No such device" remains, from cat or ffmpeg.

### No decklink

`ffmpeg -f decklink ...` fails with `Unknown input format: 'decklink'`.

Neither black nor deck nor link is mentioned by `ffmpeg -devices` (fbdev, lavfi, oss, v4l2) and `ffmpeg -formats` (about 350), either for Ubuntu's own version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, or for version N-93330-g7ff89574c7 compiled from source on 2019 Mar 13:

```
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-nonfree --disable-doc --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads
```

(Although `./configure --help` mentions `--enable-decklink`, using that yielded "ERROR: DeckLinkAPI.h not found."  `updatedb && locate DeckLinkAPI.h` finds no file with that name, either.)

The DeckLink PCI card is recognized by `hwinfo` and `lspci`.

`lsmod` reports the loaded modules `blackmagic` and `blackmagic_io`.

Maybe the PCI card is installed ok, but ffmpeg just can't reach it because I can't configure it for that.

**Edit:**  Rebooting didn't fix anything.

Comment: i've removed the `v4l2` tag, because the decklink devices don't offer V4L2-support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the "[Desktop Video](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/)" software for Linux, which supports x64 and i386 (but no arm).  It will provide *DeckLinkAPI.h* and udev should create the video device in /etc automatically.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded Blackmagic_DeckLink_SDK_10.11.4.zip, unzipped it into /foo, and then did `./configure --enable-decklink --extra-cflags='-I/foo/Blackmagic_DeckLink_SDK_10.11.1/Linux/include' ... && make`.  Then `./ffmpeg -f decklink -list_formats 1 -i 'DeckLink Mini Recorder'` listed a dozen formats.  Now I'm guessing which format produces something other than color bars.  It also looks like /dev/video0 isn't used at all.  I'll accept the answer when I've achieved actual video capture.

Comment: Just a remainder `/dev/video0` is nothing to do with Decklink Mini Monitor (or any decklink cards). Its probably was (is) a webcam or something and probably it's drivers are problematic or missing altogether.

Comment: Capturing video just required guessing which `-format_code xxxx` corresponded to what the hdmi cable was sending.  It looks like the Linux driver offers only a fraction of the formats that the box advertises.

Comment: My final working command, fyi: `./ffmpeg -y -format_code hp60 -f decklink -video_input hdmi -i 'DeckLink Mini Recorder' ...`

Comment: iirc, the blackmagic devices don't do any (or much) conversion. so if you only see a "fraction of the formats" then this is most likely because your input stream only uses a fraction of the formats (probably only a single format).